# Can someone explain what is happening with this piece of micro python

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

Just started playing with a BBC micro:bit. One of the examples has this line of code

flash = [Image().invert()*(i/9) for i in range(9, -1, -1)]

It generates set of images. In trying to figure out what is going on I wrote this piece of code

```
class Image:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        print ("init")
        for a in args:
            print (a)

    def invert(self, *args):
        print ("invert")
        for a in args:
            print (a)


flash = [Image().invert()*(i/9) for i in range(9, -1, -1)]

print ( flash )
```

which produces

```
python3 test.py 
init
invert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    flash = [Image().invert()*(i/9) for i in range(9, -1, -1)]
  File "test.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
    flash = [Image().invert()*(i/9) for i in range(9, -1, -1)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `invert()` You need to pass some int values and return any int value. In your code you are not returning any **int** or **float** value in your **invert()** function. Try this

```
class Image:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        print ("init")
        for a in args:
            print (a)

    def invert(self, *args):
        print ("invert")
        for a in args:
            return a
flash = [Image().invert(1,)*(i/9) for i in range(9, -1, -1)]
print (flash)
```

This will work

Comment: This just returns the first argument. I don't know what `invert` is supposed to do, but this just does `return args[0] if args else None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function invert isn't returning anything so when you try to multiply it you have `None*float` resulting in your described answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered Image has a * operator, ie its not the unpack operator, which was the thing that was confusing me.

Thanks for the responses